# open last modified excel spreadsheet using vba

Tags: excel, excel-2003

I have the following code that i have used to open the last modified CSV file, and have literally just changed the path name and extension, but it now doesnt work, would appreciate any pointers on where i am going wrong:

Code i am using:

```
Sub ReceiptTest()

    On Error Resume Next
    With Application.FileSearch
    .LookIn = "\\K123456\shared\IT Public\ReceiptsETE\Archive\": .Filename = "*.XLS*"
    .Execute msoSortByLastModified, msoSortOrderDescending
    For FF = 1 To .FoundFiles.Count
    If FileDateTime(.FoundFiles(FF)) > LastModDate Then
    LastModDate = FileDateTime(.FoundFiles(FF))
    lmf = .FoundFiles(FF)
    End If
    Next
    End With
    Workbooks.Open (lmf)

    End Sub
```

Thanks

Comment: are you actually run this in xl03? `Application.FileSearch` doesn't work in xl07 onwards

Comment: yes, am running in xl03

Answer (score 3):

If you're trying to open a CSV, then your filename should be *.csv*, not xls. Here's how I do it. You need to set a reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime. It will work even when you upgrade from 2003

```
Sub OpenCSV()

    Dim sFldr As String
    Dim fso As Scripting.FileSystemObject
    Dim fsoFile As Scripting.File
    Dim fsoFldr As Scripting.Folder
    Dim dtNew As Date, sNew As String

    Const sCSVTYPE As String = "Microsoft Office Excel Comma Separated Values File"

    Set fso = New Scripting.FileSystemObject

    sFldr = "C:\Documents and Settings\dick\My Documents\QBExport\"

    Set fsoFldr = fso.GetFolder(sFldr)

    For Each fsoFile In fsoFldr.Files
        If fsoFile.DateLastModified > dtNew And fsoFile.Type = sCSVTYPE Then
            sNew = fsoFile.Path
            dtNew = fsoFile.DateLastModified
        End If
    Next fsoFile

    Workbooks.Open sNew

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, but i actually want to open an .xls file not .csv

Answer (score 0):

I cannot test your code as I am using Execl 2010 and Application.FileSearch isn't supported.

I use this to find the latest modified file...

```
Sub GetLatestFile()

Dim strFolder  As String
Dim strFile    As String
Dim latestFile As String
Dim dtLast     As Date

'   assign variables
    strFolder = "C:\" 'The end of this path must have a \ on it
    strFile = Dir(strFolder & "\*.*", vbNormal)    ' Any File
'   strFile = Dir(strFolder & "\*.xls*", vbNormal) ' Excel Files
'   strFile = Dir(strFolder & "\*.csv", vbNormal)  ' CSV Files

'   loop through files to find latest modified date
    Do While strFile <> ""
        If FileDateTime(strFolder & strFile) > dtLast Then
            dtLast = FileDateTime(strFolder & strFile)
            latestFile = strFolder & strFile
        End If
        strFile = Dir
    Loop

    MsgBox latestFile

End Sub
```

Comment: thanks for this, i have amended the strFolder to reflect the path i need, and when i run the code, but the message box that pops up is blank....any thoughts?  Also, how would you open the last modified file

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I got this to work using Conman's code above with a few modification (I made changes to his code and they will be reflected if they get approved). Here is his code with those changes:

```
Sub GetLatestFile()

Dim strFolder  As String
Dim strFile    As String
Dim latestFile As String
Dim dtLast     As Date

'   assign variables
    strFolder = "C:\your\file\path\goes\here\" 'the path of the file drop folder (you need the final "\" on the directory
    strFile = Dir(strFolder & "\*.xls*", vbNormal) ' Excel Files
'   strFile = Dir(strFolder & "\*.csv", vbNormal)  ' CSV Files
'   strFile = Dir(strFolder & "\*.*", vbNormal)    ' Any File

'   loop through files to find latest modified date
    Do While strFile <> ""
        If FileDateTime(strFolder & strFile) > dtLast Then
            dtLast = FileDateTime(strFolder & strFile)
            latestFile = strFolder & strFile
        End If
        strFile = Dir
    Loop

    MsgBox latestFile

End Sub
```

You can also set strFolder by using a file dialogue and passing it into the above sub. Here is an example:

```
Sub ChooseFolder()
    Dim fd As Office.FileDialog
    Dim strFolder As String

    Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    With fd
        If .Show Then
            strFolder = .SelectedItems(1)
        End If
    End With

    GetLatestFile strFolder

End Sub

Sub GetLatestFile(strFolder  As String)

Dim strFile    As String
Dim latestFile As String
Dim dtLast     As Date

'   assign variables
    strFolder = strFolder & "\"
    strFile = Dir(strFolder & "\*.xls*", vbNormal) ' Excel Files
'   strFile = Dir(strFolder & "\*.csv", vbNormal)  ' CSV Files
'   strFile = Dir(strFolder & "\*.*", vbNormal)    ' Any File

'   loop through files to find latest modified date
    Do While strFile <> ""
        If FileDateTime(strFolder & strFile) > dtLast Then
            dtLast = FileDateTime(strFolder & strFile)
            latestFile = strFolder & strFile
        End If
        strFile = Dir
    Loop

    MsgBox latestFile

End Sub
```

I just tested both chucks of code and they work for me. Let me know if you can't get them to work.