# Open latest file and copy data to different workbook

Tags: excel, copy, vba

Im completely new to VBA. I'm trying to write macro what open latest file from folder and copy and past data from specific sheet. I need to copy data from file opened by VBA (latest file from folder) and copy data from one sheet to my current file (Expiry date sheet).

I don't know how to declare open file as workbook from where I want to copy data. Any advice?

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

'Declare the variables
Dim MyPath As String
Dim MyFile As String
Dim LatestFile As String
Dim LatestDate As Date
Dim LMD As Date


Set Y = Workbooks("TEST")


MyPath = "C:\Users\e9\Desktop\Automatyczne sprawdzanie expiry date\New folder\"


If Right(MyPath, 1) <> "\" Then MyPath = MyPath & "\"


MyFile = Dir(MyPath & "*.xls", vbNormal)


If Len(MyFile) = 0 Then
    MsgBox "No files were found...", vbExclamation
    Exit Sub
End If


Do While Len(MyFile) > 0


    LMD = FileDateTime(MyPath & MyFile)

    If LMD > LatestDate Then
        LatestFile = MyFile
        LatestDate = LMD
    End If

    MyFile = Dir


Loop

Workbooks.Open MyPath & LatestFile

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is code sample taken from various references ..

[Find Last modified file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16853966/open-last-modified-excel-spreadsheet-using-vba)
You have to add reference for the FileSystemObject .. [FileSystemObject how to add reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3233203/how-do-i-use-filesystemobject-in-vba)

Tested by adding a ActiveX button to worksheet on destination file (Book2.xlsm). Change the path and also "Book2.xlsm" to your path and filename.

```
    Dim sFldr As String
Dim fso As Scripting.FileSystemObject
Dim fsoFile As Scripting.File
Dim fsoFldr As Scripting.Folder
Dim dtNew As Date, sNew As String
Dim sFileName As String

Set fso = New Scripting.FileSystemObject

sFldr = "C:\Temp\stackoverflow\excel\"

Set fsoFldr = fso.GetFolder(sFldr)

For Each fsoFile In fsoFldr.Files
    If fsoFile.DateLastModified > dtNew Then
        sNew = fsoFile.Path
        sFileName = fsoFile.Name
        dtNew = fsoFile.DateLastModified
    End If
Next fsoFile

Workbooks.Open Filename:=sNew
Sheets("Sheet1").Copy Before:=Workbooks("Book2.xlsm").Sheets(1)
Windows(sFileName).Activate
ActiveWindow.Close
```

Answer (score 0):

Once the latest file is opened,

```
      Sheets("x").Activate
      ActiveSheet.Range("x:y").select
      selection.copy
      workbooks("x").activate
      sheets("X").activate
      activesheet.range("x").select
      selection.paste
```

Replace the xs and ys with desired names/ranges.
afterward continue your loop